# Django-mptt does not display "name" attribute

Tags: django, django-mptt

I think I am following the doc correctly but still le* weird problem occurs : MPTT template tag displays the tree nicely, indented and all, but not node.name tag (empty)

My Model

```
class Forme(MPTTModel):

name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
source_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=50, unique=True)
parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.name)

class MPTTMeta:
    order_insertion_by = ['name']
```

My View

```
def listnode(request):

nodes = Node.objects.using('hmdjango').all()


selectforme = Forme.tree.all()


allnodes = []

for n in Node.objects.using('hmdjango').all() :

    try:
        intervention = FieldDataFieldItemIntervention.objects.using('hmdjango').get(entity_id__exact=n.id)
    except FieldDataFieldItemIntervention.DoesNotExist:
        intervention.field_item_intervention_value = 'BOOM'

    try:
        forme = FieldDataFieldItemForme.objects.using('hmdjango').get(entity_id__exact=n.id)
    except FieldDataFieldItemForme.DoesNotExist:
        forme.field_item_forme_tid = 'BOOM'

    allnodes.append({'id':n.id, 'title':n.title,\

        'intervention':intervention.field_item_intervention_value, \
        'forme':forme.field_item_forme_tid})

return render_to_response('node_list.html', {'nodes':allnodes, 'formes':selectforme}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My template (I did load mptt_tags)

```
<ul class="root">
{% recursetree formes %}
    <li>
        {{ forme.name }}
        {% if not forme.is_leaf_node %}
            <ul class="children">
                {{ children }}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endrecursetree %}
```

**EDIT**
A classic loop through "formes" variables shows that I can access name attribute. Thus my guess is `recursivetree` template tag, provided by django-mptt, is my main suspect here

```
{% for forme in formes %}
  <li>{{ forme.name }}
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.

In the doc we have the example

```
<ul class="root">
{% recursetree nodes %}
    <li>
        {{ node.name }}
        {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
            <ul class="children">
                {{ children }}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endrecursetree %}
```

node is an instance of our MPTT Model. But it **has** to be call "nodes". AND no variable "nodes" should be in your template.